# FFMPEG concat with fade x264 [error]: malloc of size 23387072 failed

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge 10 videos into one, a fade to black between each video.

This seems to be working,

```
> ffmpeg -y -i
> C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\76db60cf-a653-424e-8cca-e6dcbe8645da_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\93f4ea5f-c06f-4d57-b5c8-3606f0ff39b6_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\7d71963a-d161-4be9-ade6-f1cee5a6f48e_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\3ec05fa6-1c9a-4c1b-b254-1db4800d4643_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\9b0eb5b8-23fb-4105-8a34-ddb48856f98d_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\1729a80e-1925-46b5-8ec2-e476be5b2f13_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\0c7a4f48-9381-4133-8935-5181ae06b419_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\a49990cf-7ccd-480c-86c3-1a13b661ad0d_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\5d3d02c9-2d09-4534-91f1-4c54781179fa_3840.mp4
> -i C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\096f9b3b-67bc-4f0a-bdea-b637fb45ad1f_3840.mp4
    > -filter_complex color=black:3840x1920:d=147.31495999999999[base];
[0:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=6.9:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=13.291992:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(5.399999999999999/TB)[v1];
[2:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=11.375:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(18.691992/TB)[v2];
[3:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=12.958984:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(30.066992/TB)[v3];
[4:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=17.666992:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(43.025976/TB)[v4];
[5:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=14.541992:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(60.692968/TB)[v5];
[6:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=13.94:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(75.23496/TB)[v6];
[7:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=12.66:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(89.17496/TB)[v7];
[8:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=17.74:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(101.83496/TB)[v8];
[9:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=11.86:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(119.57495999999999/TB)[v9];
[10:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=15.38:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(131.43496/TB)[v10];
[base][v0]overlay[over1];
[over1][v1]overlay[over2];
[over2][v2]overlay[over3];
[over3][v3]overlay[over4];
[over4][v4]overlay[over5];
[over5][v5]overlay[over6];
[over6][v6]overlay[over7];
[over7][v7]overlay[over8];
[over8][v8]overlay[over9];
[over9][v9]overlay[over10];
[over10][v10]overlay[over11]
> -map [over11] C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\2c10347e-b16c-4c18-ab8a-db14b9e3bc32.mp4
```

But I get the out of memory error

> x264 [error]: malloc of size 23387072 failedme=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
>   Video encoding failed

Is there anyway around this? Am I better to do each video individually?

Thanks

Comment: If there's no overlap, use the concat filter. Remove the color filter. Remove the offsets from the setpts filters (`+5.399..` etc). Remove the overlay filters. Add `[v0][v1][v2]..[v10]concat=n=11`

Comment: Thanks. Will this lose the fade to black between each video?

Comment: If it's a crossfade, then yes, since those are overlapping segments. But the error suggests you are running this on an underpowered rig. There's nothing wrong with the current command.

Comment: Thanks no it's a big machine (16g ram), should be able to handle it. It can handle 3, but when I try 4 I get a memory error.

Comment: Are you doing `4k`? I see `3840` in the file names. Are you using a 64-bit `ffmpeg` build and is `x264` the latest version?